# Check failed: top_shape[j] == bottom[i]->shape(j): for Concat layer in 3D data

Tags: caffe, image-segmentation, pycaffe, matcaffe, semantic-segmentation

I am trying to train [3D-Unet](https://lmb.informatik.uni-freiburg.de/resources/opensource/3dUnet_miccai2016_with_BN.prototxt) in `caffe`. The width, height and depth of different volumes is different. The input shape of the first volume in HDF5 dataset is `1 1 104 281 389` (NxCxDxHxW), when it reaches to the `Concat layer` (concat_d2c_u2a-b), it is raising an error, which it is inputs are with the following two shapes:

- 1 256 19 64 91 scaled2c_relu_d2c_0_split_1
- 1 512 12 56 84 scaleu2a

How can I solve this issue? Is it because of the order of dimensions?

```
I0708 22:19:59.811188 30282 layer_factory.cpp:74] Creating layer concat_d2c_u2a-b
I0708 22:19:59.811198 30282 net.cpp:185] Creating Layer concat_d2c_u2a-b
I0708 22:19:59.811200 30282 net.cpp:549] concat_d2c_u2a-b <- scaleu2a
I0708 22:19:59.811203 30282 net.cpp:549] concat_d2c_u2a-b <- scaled2c_relu_d2c_0_split_1
I0708 22:19:59.811208 30282 net.cpp:515] concat_d2c_u2a-b -> u2b
F0708 22:19:59.811223 30282 concat_layer.cpp:45] Check failed: top_shape[j] == bottom[i]->shape(j) (12 vs. 19) All inputs must have the same shape, except at concat_axis.
*** Check failure stack trace: ***
```

Answer (score 0):

[`"Concat"`](http://caffe.help/manual/layers/concat.html) operation puts two (or more) Blobs together. For example, if you have two 1D Blobs `x1` of dimension 10 and `x2` of dimension 15, concatenating them will result with a 1D vector `y` of dimension 25.
In order to concat higher dimensional Blobs, you **must** have all dimensions of the Blobs identical, apart from the concat dimension. For example, if you want to concat `n1`x`c1`x`h1`x`w1` Blob with `n1`x`c2`x`h2`x`w2` along the channel dimensions, then you **must** have `n1==n2`, `h1==h2` and `w1==w2` and your output Blob will be `n`x`(c1+c2)`x`h`x`w`.
Note that you cannot concat along channel dimension if any of the non-channel dimension do not match.

In your case none of the dimensions matches, therefore you cannot concat. You need to review your architecture and verify that you are padding/pooling/striding the right way to ensure the dimensions will match for concatenation.